# How can I test for html5 audio, video, and specific css properties?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'd like to create a function that checks for a list of things, as listed above, and then returns true if they all check out and false if they don't.

Can someone link me to an example, or explain how to do this?

Comment: What does it mean **"test for html5 audio, video, and specific css properties"** ?!

Comment: It's not clear what do You want. Do You need a way to check is browser support specific properties/features or not?

Comment: [DETECTING HTML5 FEATURES](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html)

Comment: Also, check http://html5please.us/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). It will let you do all sorts of HTML5 and CSS3 dependency checks.

Comment: Yea I was looking at this but I don't need something that heavy so I was just posting to see if I could easily do this on my own

Comment: I suppose I will just use modernizer

Comment: Using the Modernizr website you can create a custom version with just the checks you really need. Click on production and create your personal build. See http://www.modernizr.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like modernizr?

http://www.modernizr.com/

Modernizr is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you build the next generation of HTML5 and CSS3-powered websites.